# How do I get SvcConfigEditor.exe onto a server?

Tags: wcf

Over a year ago I wrote a WCF service, which runs on a Windows 2003 Server, under the auspices of a Windows Service (which I also wrote).  (I wrote it using VS 2008.)  I've not had a chance to continue working with it for a long time, but would now like to pick up where I left off back then.  However, now I'm trying to use VS 2010, and see if I can interact with it.

The first thing I did was run SvcUtil from the command line, to get the information I would need to put into my App.Config file.  However, it gave me an error (#415) saying that the server had rejected the network request.  I've been asking around as to how I can fix this problem, and was told that I should run SvcConfigEditor.exe on the server in order to get better logging information.  So I RDP onto the server and tried running it.  Only, it isn't installed on the server.  The .NET Framework 2 and 3.5 are installed, but I wouldn't think it would matter if .NET 4 was installed on the server, if I'm trying to run SvcConfigEditor.exe from .NET 3.5.

Bottom line: how do I get SvcConfigEditor.exe onto the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just copy your config from the server to you workstation and then run svcconfigeditor then copy it back to the server.  Your config is just a text file so treat it as such.

Comment: WOW, cool, I hadn't thought of that.  OK, so are you talking about the Machine.Config file, or the App.Config file used by the WCF service?

Comment: The app config file it has all the configurations

Answer (score 5):

It installs it with WindowsSDK for Windows Server.

If you don't see it available in Start > All Programs > Windows SDK > Tool > Service Configuation Editor OR can't find the file "SvcConfigEditor.exe" you haven't to added the feature.

To add...

1. Control Panel > Programs and Feature > (Right-click) Microsoft Windows SDK for Server > Change
2. Check on Developer Tools> Windows Development Tools > .NET Development Tools

After the install of the feature, you should see it now.

Answer (score 4):

Get it from your local development machine where Visual Studio is installed:

**Microsoft Service Configuration Editor**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\SvcConfigEditor.exe

You might want to get the following tools as well:

**Service Trace Viewer** (Of you have WCF tracing enabled)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\SvcTraceViewer.exe

**WCF Test Client**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe

Comment: what if you have no SDK directory

Comment: @CoffeeAddict then you need to install it somewhere.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138